# How to solve IPFS Desktop stuck in "IPFS is starting"?

Tags: ipfs, cli

I just install IPFS CLI and Desktop then run it.

I have no idea what to do with my IPFS Desktop where stuck in "IPFS is starting", so many ways I have done with to solve this problem:

- restart computer
- quit app and open again
- reinstalling

but, no one works for me, can someone help how to solve this and why this happens? So, I could learn from this case.

Thank you

add:
I'm using Mac M1

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

by change the PORT in `.ipfs` folder, that caused I have another program that runs in same PORT on my computer. So I have to change it.